# PHP - Get the request line from the headers

Tags: php, request, request-headers

HTTP requests have headers, which can be obtained via `getallheaders()`, but the first line of the request isn't a header. Instead it's the request line which looks like:

`GET /path/to/resource HTTP/1.1`

or, with GET parameters,

`GET /path/to/resource?var1=val1&var2=val2 HTTP/1.1`

How would I get this request line in PHP? Or would I need to rebuild it with $_SERVER vars?

Comment: Reconstruct from CGI env vars: REQUEST_METHOD, REQUEST_URI, SERVER_PROTOCOL, or capture per mod_rewrite into a separate var.

Answer (score 0):

So for now (as per @mario's suggestion), I'm doing,

```
$requestLine = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']
       . ' ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
       . ' ' . $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'];
```

which seems to work fine.

If anyone has an alternate solution that would get the exact string, I'll accept it instead, but otherwise this should suffice.